# Replace a word in a string by a tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Lets consider the following HTML snippet:

```
html = '''
 <p>
  The chairman of European Union leaders, Donald Tusk, will meet May in London on Thursday, a day after the bloc’s Brexit negotiator weakened sterling by issuing another warning to Britain, which is due to leave the bloc in March 2019.
 </p>
'''
```

Let's turn it into a BeautifulSoup object:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

I would like to transform that soup object so that its HTML output is:

```
'''
    <p>
      The chairman of European Union leaders, <span style="color : red"> Donald Tusk </span>, will meet May in London on Thursday, a day after the bloc’s Brexit negotiator weakened sterling by issuing another warning to Britain, which is due to leave the bloc in March 2019.
     </p>
'''
```

I found on [the doc page of BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring-and-new-tag) couple of examples of how to replace a string, create a new tag, or even insert a new tag at a specific location in the tree, *but not* how to **add a new tag in the middle of a string** like in my use case.

Any help very welcome.

Comment: I'm curious, how will the modified string be used?

Comment: @Life is complex i'm trying to mark certain news articles that i downloaded for an nlp project

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I was asking, because I was able to this with regex and string replace with your example, but I don't know how it works with full HTML from BS.

Comment: Why not first modify the html code and **then** turn it into a BeautifulSoup object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let me say, thanks for posting this question, because it was a very interesting coding problem.

I spent sometime looking at this problem and finally decided to throw an answer into the ring.

I attempted to use `insert_before()` and `insert_after()` from `BeautifulSoup` to modified the `<p>` tag in your example HTML. I also looked at using `extend()` and `append()` from `BeautifulSoup`. After dozens of attempts, I just could not get the results you requested.

The code below seems to accomplish the requested HTML modification based on a keyword (e.g., Donald Tusk). I used `replace_with()`
from `BeautifulSoup` to replace the original tag in the HTML with `new_tag()` from `BeautifulSoup.`

The code works, but I'm sure that it can be refined.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

raw_html = """
<p> This is a test. </p>
<p>The chairman of European Union leaders, Donald Tusk, will meet May in London on Thursday, a day after the bloc’s Brexit negotiator weakened sterling by issuing another warning to Britain, which is due to leave the bloc in March 2019.</p>
<p> This is also a test. </p>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'lxml')

# find the tag that contains the keyword Donald Tusk
original_tag = soup.find('p',text=re.compile(r'Donald Tusk'))

if original_tag:
  # modify text in the tag that was found in the HTML
  tag_to_modify = str(original_tag.get_text()).replace('Donald Tusk,', '<span style="color:red">Donald Tusk</span>,')

  print (tag_to_modify)
  # outputs
  The chairman of European Union leaders, <span style="color:red">Donald Tusk</span>, will meet May in London on Thursday, a day after the bloc’s Brexit negotiator weakened sterling by issuing another warning to Britain, which is due to leave the bloc in March 2019.

  # create a new <p> tag in the soup
  new_tag = soup.new_tag('p')

  # add the modified text to the new tag
  # setting a tag’s .string attribute replaces the contents with the new string
  new_tag.string = tag_to_modify

  # replace the original tag with the new tag
  old_tag = original_tag.replace_with(new_tag)

  # formatter=None, BeautifulSoup will not modify strings on output
  # without this the angle brackets will get turned into “&lt;”, and “&gt;”
  print (soup.prettify(formatter=None))
  # outputs 
  <html>
    <body>
      <p>
        This is a test.
      </p>
      <p>
        The chairman of European Union leaders, <span style="color:red">Donald Tusk</span>, will meet May in London on Thursday, a day after the bloc’s Brexit negotiator weakened sterling by issuing another warning to Britain, which is due to leave the bloc in March 2019.
      </p>
      <p>
        This is also a test.
      </p>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a loop, go through each word in the string, once you find the string your looking for (using whatever method works, regular expressions would be useful) then use the **Tag.insert(position, "found_word")**

Comment: thx for your reply - my understanding is that the insert position refers to other tags.Example from the doc here: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#insert.
Replace_with (https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with) seems to be the only way to edit string in place, but its puzzling how to edit and add a tag in the middle of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Regular Expressions. Hope this snippet helps.

```
import re

def highlight_matches(query, text):
    def span_matches(match):
        html = '<span style="color : red">{0}</span>'
        return html.format(match.group(0))
    return re.sub(query, span_matches, text, flags=re.I)
```

Comment: it seems to me that the html graph (soup) needs to be modified with bs4 objects rather than html as string. But i 'll try that.